# jasper report showing nothing and getting error NullPointer Error on Netbeans

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

**report.java**

```
     byte[] pdfbyte = null;
        try {
            dbcon connect = new dbcon();
            ServletContext context = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
            String compiledFileName = context.getRealPath("/jasper/report3.jasper");
            System.out.print(compiledFileName);
            // String var = request.getParameter("var").toString();
            //String res = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your name?", "Enter your name",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

            File reportFile = new File(compiledFileName);
            HashMap parameters = new HashMap();
//            // parameters.put("itemName", var);
            parameters.put("ReportTitle", "MyReport");
//            parameters.put("BaseDir", reportFile.getParentFile());
//            parameters.put("EmpNo", 32504);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
            Connection conn = connect.dbstate().getConnection();
            try {

                try {
                    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(compiledFileName, parameters, conn);
                    pdfbyte = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.print("E" + e);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("*** Could not create compiled jasper file: " + ex.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    connect.dbstate().close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    System.out.println("could not close  databse after filling the report ");
                }
            }
            ServletOutputStream outstream = response.getOutputStream();

            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setContentLength(pdfbyte.length);
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"Report.pdf\"");
            outstream.write(pdfbyte);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Library**

[image]

I'm getting following error on Netbeans

```
SEVERE: A web application registered the JBDC driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Ejava.lang.NullPointerExceptionjava.lang.NullPointerExceptionjava.lang.NullPointerException
        at jasper.Report.processRequest(Report.java:63)
        at jasper.Report.doGet(Report.java:75)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Is the report being generated at `pdfFilePath`? - Also, personally, I'd avoid compiling the reports at run time, as this is quite a slow process, you should be able to pre-compile then and simply use the output to fill the report...

Comment: yes.. I want to download/generate the report to server folder `jasperReport` and same time report should be displayed on the browser.

Comment: You could output the report to HTML and server the result.  Otherwise you should be trying to serve the link...I think, being a while since I've tried anything like this ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for your suggestion, but could you please share some part of code of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wasn't any problem with code, I change all the library to latest updated one like `jasperreport-4.5.1.jar` to `jasperreport-5.1.0.jar` and It worked !!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to pre-compile you report's, like @MadProgrammer told. To send a report from servlet to a client (previwe on webbrowser or direct download) i use this:

```
...
// trying get the report
        try {

        // getting de real path
        String reportPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath(reportFileName);

        //
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();

        // here you can specify the condition to print, if conditionVoolean is true it will do a direct download
        if (conditionBoolean) {
            fileName = "your file name to direct download";
            httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName +".pdf");
        }

        // 
        byte[] bytes;

        // get the filled report in bytes
        bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperReport, parameter, conn);

        if (bytes != null && bytes.length > 0) {

            // specifying the type of file/content to browser
            httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");

            httpServletResponse.setContentLength(bytes.length);

            ServletOutputStream ouputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();

            ouputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

            ouputStream.flush();

            // closing the stream line
            ouputStream.close();
        }
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    }
    catch (JRException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
...
```

Att: sorry for portuguese comments. Its my native language.

Hope it helps ^^

Comment: Your solution wasn't helpful. I'm still getting blank screen. No pdf generated.

Comment: Ok, lets try resolve this. the exception continue there? and, if your resultset is empty, it will show a blank report. confirm ur query bro?

Comment: thanks bro, I checked all and yesterday googled and found actual problem. It was because, I was using some old version library. I downloaded latest one It worked !! So, I guess my code was correct.